# Is it possible to have a non scrolling row within a ScrollViewer?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer, non-scrolling

Since I need to have a portion (but not all) of my page in a Scroll Viewer, I've got a winrt-xaml layout like so:

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I have column titles for the second grid, which is inside the scroll viewer. If I put the column titles *outside* the grid (placing them in the last row of the outer grid) it is difficult if not impossible to make them align with the columns in the inner grid. But if I leave them in the inner grid (inside the ScrollViewer) they can scroll out of sight.

SO: is it possible to freeze that first row into place? Or, OTOH, is if, after all, readily doable to have the column widths in "Grid1" (the outer grid) align seamlessly with the column widths in "Grid2" (the inner grid)?

### UPDATE

I can't see why, but it's not quite working, using option #2 in Juan's answer. The only problem is that both the "Longitude" and the "Color" labels are displayed way to the right of where they should be - all the others align perfectly, and their horizontal alignment property is set to "Left," so I don't see why these two are not cooperating. Here's the xaml:

Group Name

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Title</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center">Address</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >Latitude</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Longitude</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Center">Color</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation1" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 1</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle1" Margin="4" MinWidth="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation2" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 2</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle2" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation3" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 3</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle3" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation4" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 4</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle4" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation5" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 5</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle5" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation6" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 6</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle6" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="6">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation7" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 7</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle7" Margin="4" Width="200"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockLocation8" FontSize="20" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Location 8</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxTitle8" Margin="4" Width="200" LostFocus="CheckForAllRecordsValid" ></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="240" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress6" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress7" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxAddress8" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" LostFocus="CheckForAllRecordsValid" ></TextBox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" MinWidth="120"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude6" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude7" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLatitude8" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" Margin="4" LostFocus="CheckForAllRecordsValid" ></TextBox>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4" MinWidth="120"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude6" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude7" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLongitude8" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="5" Margin="4" LostFocus="CheckForAllRecordsValid"></TextBox>

        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="CmbxColor1_OnSelectionChanged"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor6" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor7" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxColor8" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="6" Margin="4,4,0,4" MinWidth="200" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" LostFocus="CheckForAllRecordsValid" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10" >or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="7,10,6,10">or</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="6,10">and</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

### UPDATE 2

Since I'm still having an alignment problem (the grid columns above don't always align, width-wise, with the grid columns below), I'm posting here, as requested, my Grid XAML. First, the top grid:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="320"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col2Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col3Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col4Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col5Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col6Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="120"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

...now, the second (inner) grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridDynamicRowsParent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="320"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1Grid2" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col2Grid2" Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3Grid2" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col4Grid2" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col5Grid2" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col6Grid2" Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Also, the controls are "rubbery" - when I enter a value for which they are not wide enough, they will expand sideways to accommodate some of the additional space; I don't want this - the controls (TextBoxes) should remain the same width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two different approaches for your case:

1. Create a SharedSizeGroup for the columns ([see this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/guy/archive/2009/06/30/wpf-grid-shared-size-groups.aspx) -one between a lot out there- as example )
2. Name the columns in the second grid and set the columns in the first grid to bind their Width to the ActualWidth property of the corresponding columns, something like this:

   ```
   <Page>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Name="Grid1">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1Grid2, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <ScrollViewer>
           <Grid Name="Grid2">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Name="Col1Grid2" Width="*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Name="Col2Grid2" Width="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         </ScrollViewer>
      </StackPanel>
    </Page>
   ```

See if you can get the desired behavior with any of these options. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer and for the upvote. Which approach did you use?

Comment: #2, which *almost* worked; I've still got some weird behavior with two of the textblocks not aligning, though; I updated my post\question.

Comment: @ClayShannon the only thing I see is that the "Color" textblock is not aligned to the left, but the "Longitude" actually is... I imagine they are pretty standard, but try to post the columndefinitions for the grid

Comment: Okay, I'm appending the column definitions to my original post.

Comment: Aren't they aligning because of the scrollbar of the scrollviewer? If not, make sure the scrollviewer containing the second grid has its Padding set to 0, since none of the grids has its Margin property set (maybe set Padding and Margin explicitly to 0?).

Comment: I added an explicit 0 margin to both grids, and to the scrollviewer, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Padding too? I can't see anything else wrong, sorry not to be more helpful here :-S